# Unable to remove /home in codeigniter from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I am running in a problem with codeigniter. a client of mine has given me his script for modification which basically opens pages as https://example.com/home or https://example.com/page-name now my client wants me to remove only the /home when a user opens the website there should not be /home in the url.

i really am clueless how to acheive it. please someone help me out here i would appreciate it.

here is the htaccess

```
# Case 1
# -------------------------------------------------------#
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
# -------------------------------------------------------#  

# Case 2
# -------------------------------------------------------#
# RewriteEngine on
# ExpiresActive On
# ExpiresDefault A2592000
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
# RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|public|assets|uploads|themes|install|backups|updates|asset|mob|robots\.txt|curl.php)
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
# -------------------------------------------------------#

# Case 3
# -------------------------------------------------------#
# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
# </IfModule>
# -------------------------------------------------------#

# Case 4
# -------------------------------------------------------#
# RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
# -------------------------------------------------------#

# Case 6 for SSL Hosting
# -------------------------------------------------------#
# RewriteEngine on
# ExpiresActive On
# ExpiresDefault A2592000
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
# RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|public|assets|uploads|themes|install|updates|asset|mob|robots\.txt)
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
# -------------------------------------------------------#

# case 5
# -------------------------------------------------------#
#RewriteEngine On
#DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
# -------------------------------------------------------#
```

and here is the codes from routes.php

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

// EANSLUG => properties
$route['phpinfo'] = "home/phpinfo";
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = 'home';

$route['m-(.*)'] = 'home'; // for new menu
$route['responsive'] = 'home/responsive'; // responsive check
$route['pull'] = 'home/pull'; // git pull origin master

$route['admin/modules/ajaxController(.*)'] = 'admin/ajaxController$1';
$route['admin/settings/modules/add'] = 'admin/modulesController/add';
$route['admin/settings/modules/edit(.*)'] = 'admin/modulesController/edit$1';
$route['admin/modules/delete(.*)'] = 'admin/modulesController/delete$1';
$route['admin/settings/modules(.*)'] = 'admin/modulesController$1';
$route['admin/modules(.*)'] = 'admin/modulesController$1';
$route['admin/flights/settings'] = 'flights/flightsback/setting_routes';
$route['admin/flights/flightsback/add_settings'] = 'flights/flightsback/add_settings';


$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['supplier-register'] = 'home/supplier_register';
$route[str_replace("/", "",EANSLUG)] = 'Ean';
$route[EANSLUG.'loadMore'] = 'Ean/loadMore';
$route[EANSLUG.'listings/(:any)'] = 'Ean/listings/$1';
$route['properties/search/(.*)'] = 'Ean/search/$1';
$route[EANSLUG.'reservation/?(:any)?'] = 'Ean/reservation/$1';
$route[str_replace("/", "",EANSLUG)."/?(:any)?"] = 'Ean/index/$1';
$route[EANSLUG.'itin'] = 'Ean/itin';
$route[EANSLUG.'hotel/(:any)/(:any)/?(:any)'] = 'Ean/hotel/$1/$2/$3';
$route['car'] = 'Cartrawler';
$route['flightst'] = 'Travelstart';
$route['admin/flightst(.*)'] = 'Travelstart/Travelstartback$1';
$route['air'] = 'Travelpayouts';
$route['flightsw/search/(.*)'] = 'Wegoflights/flight_results/$1';
$route['flightsw'] = 'Wegoflights';
$route['hotelsc'] = 'Hotelscombined';
$route['sitemap\.xml'] = "Sitemap";
$route['getCities'] = "Home/getCities";
$route['visa'] = 'Ivisa';
$route['visa/booking'] = 'Ivisa/booking';
$route['visa/confirmation'] = 'Ivisa/confirmation';
$route['visa/invoice/(:any)'] = 'Ivisa/invoice/$1';
$route['admin/ivisa/bookings'] = 'ivisa/ivisaback/bookings';

$route['license'] = 'home/license';
```

can someone please help me out in here with a solution.

Thanks alot

Comment: Did you try $route['default_controller'] = "";

Comment: @Wiszh yes tried but still it shows when go to example.com/home is what i get